# Jstree show context menu conditionally

Tags: conditional-statements, contextmenu, jstree

This code below shows my attempt to show a jstree context menu only at level 1.

The menu shows at level one and selection of the menu items shows an alert.
The menu **does not show** at level 2 which is fine and what I want.

But, after selecting a level 2 node, then selecting a level 1 node the menu  appears as it should, but selection of the menu items does nothing.

Any help appreciated.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/NervousElk/4p5hqg0r/17/ fiddle

```
document.getElementById("gobtn").addEventListener("click", buildtree);

function buildtree()
{               
        $('#ttstafftree').jstree(
        {           
        plugins: ["wholerow",  "json_data", "ui", "themes", "sort", "state",  "contextmenu"], 
        'core' : 
            {                                   
                "check_callback": true,                 
                'data' : 
                    [
                    { "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root 1" },
                    { "id" : "ajson1-1", "parent" : "ajson1", "text" : "a" },                       
                    { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root 2" },
                    { "id" : "ajson2-1", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "b" },                       
                    ]
            },

            "contextmenu": 
            {                                                                               
                "items": 
                {
                  opt1: 
                  {
                    label: "opt 1",                     
                    action: function(data) 
                    {
                     alert('opt 1')                      
                    }                                                                                       
                  },

                  opt2: 
                  {
                    label: "opt 2",
                    action: function(data) 
                    {
                     alert('opt 2')                      
                    }                                                                           
                  }                                                                               
                }                
            },                      
        })  

        .on('show_contextmenu.jstree', function(e, reference, element) 
        {                           
            if ( reference.node.parents.length != 1) 
            {                             
               $('.vakata-context').remove();                          
            }

        });      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing the `vakata-context` element to hide the context menu for leaf nodes. Although I'm not too certain of this, to me it seems that this breaks the event handlers set on the context menu so they don't work anymore. Looking at the source code for the context menu, jsTree internally uses `$.vakata.context.hide()` to hide the tree. You could use that in your event handler for the `show_contextmenu.jstree` event.

```
.on('show_contextmenu.jstree', function (e, reference, element) {
      if (reference.node.parents.length != 1) {
          $.vakata.context.hide();
          //$('.vakata-context').css('display',"none");
      }
});
```

Comment: That fixed Stephen S. I'm a bit new to Stackoverflow, how do I attribute to you?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, you could just mark the answer as correct if it solves your problem...Thanks